Glossaries package and tex4ebook show the lack of a linebreak up from letter B in the glossary
This is a MWE to show in the epub the lack of a linebreak up from letter B wording in the glossary.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{GlossaryTest.bib}
@entry{Alpha,
    name={Alpha},
    description={Erster griechischer Buchstabe}}
@entry{Automobil,
    name={Automobil},
    description={Mit Motor betriebenes Fahrzeug}}
@entry{Ammersee,
    name={Ammersee},
    description={Lake in South Germany}}
@entry{Babel,
    name={Babel},
    description={Es war einmal ein Turm, der noch heute irrt umher}}
@entry{Berlin,
    name={Berlin},
    description={Hauptstadt von Deutschland}}
@entry{Caesar,
    name={Casesar},
    description={Wurde ermordet}}
@entry{Celsius,
    name={Celsius},
    description={Ein Wissenschaftler, nach dem eine Temperaturskala benannt ist}}   
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[record=nameref,
style=index,
nogroupskip=false,
nonumberlist,
postdot,
toc=false]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={GlossaryTest},
selection=all,
sort=de-GE]

\begin{document}
    
\gls{Alpha}

\gls{Ammersee}

\gls{Automobil}

\gls{Babel}

\gls{Berlin}

\gls{Caesar}

\gls{Celsius}

\printunsrtglossary[title=Glossar]

\end{document}

You have

run pdflatex
run bib2gls --group Yourlatexdocument.tex
run pdflatex

Then run
tex4ebook -a debug -c Config.cfg -e build-fc-i-2.lua
as following:
Config.cfg:
% save the clearpage before it is redefined by tex4ht
\let\oldclrearpage\clearpage
% define macro for newpage insertion
\def\mypagebreak{\Configure{newpage}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="newpage"></div>}}}
%
\Preamble{xhtml,no-cut,3,info}
\catcode`\:=11
        \Configure{footnotetext}
   {\ifTag{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}
   {\expandafter\ifx\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
       \:warning{Multiple footnote texts for mark \FNnum}%
    \else \csname a:footnote-text\endcsname\fi
   }
   {}%
%
    \csname a:footnote-mark\endcsname
\AnchorLabel
\Link{}{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}%
    \NoFonts%
   }
   {\EndNoFonts \EndLink\csname b:footnote-mark\endcsname
}
   {\ifTag{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
}
   {\expandafter\ifx\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
    \else  \csname b:footnote-text\endcsname\fi
   }
   {}%
\expandafter\global\expandafter
   \let\csname (fn\FNnum x\minipageNum
)\endcsname\def
}
\catcode`\:=12
\Configure{CoverMimeType}{image/jpeg}
\Configure{CoverImage}{}{}

\mypagebreak
\Css{.newpage{page-break-before:always;}}
% modify \Configure{BODY} so our confiurations work on all extracted pages
\Configure{@BODY}{\def\clearpage{\bgroup\mypagebreak\oldclrearpage\egroup}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\global\let\clearpage\oldclrearpage\Configure{newpage}{}}
%\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
%\renewcommand\textbf[1]{#1}%
%\renewcommand\LaTeX{LaTeX}
%}
\begin{document}
\Configure{DocumentLanguage}{de}
\Configure{OpfScheme}{ISBN}
\Configure{UniqueIdentifier}{3-0000-1111-X}
\EndPreamble

And build-fc-i-2.lua
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:makeindex {language="de"}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end

It seems that up from letter B in the glossary there needs to be a linebreak between the glossary-entries.
Is there any quick fix to this?
Thank you for support.
UPDATE 1:
The MWE with the links for the glossary entries is the following, it just differs from the above by including the hyperref package. The hidelinks does not work as thought by me. Formatting the tex and the glossary and the tex4ebook is as above too.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{GlossaryTest.bib}
@entry{Alpha,
    name={Alpha},
    description={Erster griechischer Buchstabe}}
@entry{Automobil,
    name={Automobil},
    description={Mit Motor betriebenes Fahrzeug}}
@entry{Ammersee,
    name={Ammersee},
    description={Lake in South Germany}}
@entry{Babel,
    name={Babel},
    description={Es war einmal ein Turm, der noch heute irrt umher}}
@entry{Berlin,
    name={Berlin},
    description={Hauptstadt von Deutschland}}
@entry{Caesar,
    name={Casesar},
    description={Wurde ermordet}}
@entry{Celsius,
    name={Celsius},
    description={Ein Wissenschaftler, nach dem eine Temperaturskala benannt ist}}   
\end{filecontents}

\ifdefined\HCode% hidelinks für glossary entries funktioniert nicht
\usepackage[tex4ht,hyperindex=true,hidelinks,hyperfootnotes=true,]{hyperref}
\else
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\fi
\usepackage[record=nameref,
style=index,
nogroupskip=false,
nonumberlist,
postdot,
toc=false]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={GlossaryTest},
selection=all,
sort=de-GE]


\begin{document}
    

\gls{Alpha}

\gls{Ammersee}

\gls{Automobil}

\gls{Babel}

\gls{Berlin}

\gls{Caesar}

\gls{Celsius}

\printunsrtglossary[title=Glossar]

\end{document}


Try this version of glossaries.4ht:
% glossaries.4ht (2022-12-04-09:02), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2008-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-12-04-09:02}

\def\:tempc#1#2{\Link[ class="glossary"]{#1}{}#2\EndLink}
\HLet\@glslink\:tempc
\def\:tempc#1#2{\Link{}{#1}\EndLink#2}
\HLet\@glstarget\:tempc
\def\:tempc#1 #2\@nil{%
 \toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@#1}%
 \ifx\\#2\\%
   \edef\x{\the\toks@}%
   \ifx\x\empty
   \else
%     \hyperlink{\glsentrycounter.\the\toks@}%
                {\the\toks@}%
   \fi
 \else
   \@gls@ReturnAfterFi{%
     \@gls@removespaces#2\@nil
   }%
 \fi
}
\HLet\@gls@removespaces\:tempc


\Configure{@begin}{theglossary}{
  \Configure{theindex}{\a:theglossary}{\b:theglossary}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
  \def\idx:item{\SaveEverypar\ht:everypar{}}
  \let\end:theidx\empty
}

\NewConfigure{glossentry}{2}

\Configure{glossentry}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="glossary">}}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
\def\:tempa#1{\a:glossentry\o:glossentry:{#1}\b:glossentry}
\HLet\glossentry\:tempa

\NewConfigure{glsgroupskip}{1}
\Configure{glsgroupskip}{\ifvmode\Ignore\Par\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="glsgroupskip"></div>\Hnewline}}
\Css{.glsgroupskip{margin-bottom:1rem;}}
\Css{.glsgroupskip + .glsgroupskip{margin-bottom: 0;}}
\def\:tempa{\a:glsgroupskip}
\HLet\glsgroupskip\:tempa


\Hinput{glossaries}
\endinput

It adds some formatting for glossary entries, it also adds support for the skip between alphabet groups.
This is the result:


Thank you, great. That works as intended. Will a next update of tex4ebook/tex4ht include that?

Is it possible to suppress in the epub the blue glossary entries underlined as links when the entries appear in the text? I tried the option hidelinks in the 'hyperref' package but this doesn't work. In our MWE there are no links at all, which is to me not approriate for my current project. Is there a way to get an option for this? Which means to have links for the glossary entries hidden and as the same as the surrounding text. But as links working to point the glossary at the end. @michal.h21 ?

@Thomkrates I will need a MWE for that. It depends on how you make these links. You can use CSS to change colors of links, that seems like easiest thing to do.

I addad a MWE in Update 1 above. There is only the hyperref package and options come along with it. The result show the glossary entries in the text with hyperlinks (blue underlined). I would like to see it as same as the text (like in the xurl package the option same).

@Thomkrates just add this line to your config file: \Css{a, a:visited{color: black; text-decoration: none;}}. If you want to have underlined links, remove text-decoration: none;.

Ok, thank you. That seems comprehensible. I have a glossary and an index in my project. Would it be possible to mark the links for glossary and index differently? So that the glossary links will be the same appearance as the text. But the index links would be in blue color underlined? Would that be possible?

@Thomkrates use the updated .4ht file and this configuration: \Css{a.glossary, a.glossary:visited{color: black; text-decoration: none;}}

Yes, that works as intended, Michal. Thank you for this time.
